# What is the probability that a villager is a nitwit (green coat)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a villager breeder, and I want the villagers become employed. However, I am getting piles of nitwits as a negative byproduct. I don't dispose of these villagers, so this starts to become a problem. I want as many "non-nitwit" villagers. What is the probability that a baby villager grows into a nitwit (green coat) villager?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't dispose of the nitwits? One would think that slavery-based breeding pens would be *below* occasional murder on the scales of atrocities...

Comment: @Dragomok I use the nitwits in an iron farm. Talking about your "slavery-based breeding pens," I don't use that kind of breeders xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the wiki's page on Villager](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Nitwit):

> In Bedrock Edition, every baby villager has a 10% chance to become a nitwit.

I'm not sure what the probability is for Java Edition though.

This also may be useful:

> In Bedrock Edition it is currently possible to turn a nitwit into a zombie villager, and cure them using a Potion of Weakness and a golden apple, and they will turn into a normal unemployed villager.

Comment: Oh, so you can actually de-nimwit them!? 2 years I've been playing and never thought of trying that. Thanks, that was helpful